# invalid attribute: :for (Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException)

Tags: css-selectors, watir

using Watir has the title error
Need to set checkbox:

```
<label for="adr-eq" class="checkbox">Ok</label>
```

it works for:

```
ff.element(:css => 'label.checkbox:nth-child(12)').click
```

but why it doesn't work for:

```
ff.checkbox(:for => 'adr-eq').set
ff.element(:for => 'adr-eq').click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watir only allows locating elements using attributes that are valid for the element type (based on the HTML specifications). The `for` attribute is not valid for all elements or input elements. As a result, you get the `Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException`.

If you look at the HTML you are trying to interact with, as well as the working CSS-selector, the element type is a label. The `for` attribute is valid for labels (and a couple of other elements). As a result, if you tell Watir to locate a label element, you can then use the `:for` locator.

To click the label using the `for` attribute:

```
ff.label(:for => 'adr-eq').click
```

If you want to use the `Checkbox#set` method, you will need to locate the element by the `id` attribute, which should match the `for` attribute:

```
ff.checkbox(:id => 'adr-eq').set
```

Comment: thank you a lot, it works for label and doesn't work with checkbox. but problem solved.